# How do I find appropriate UV coordinates at seams in geometry nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes

In the example image embedded below, the positions are offset inward if their uv coordinate (y) equals 0.5. You can see that the seam has a uv coordinate of 0.5 for some reason. I believe that it is because it is average 0 and 1 (where it would be on either side of the UV island). For my project to work, I would be happy with it using either 0 or 1. Any ideas on achieving that?

[image]

I have tried splitting the geometry at the seams, but that messes up the normals.

Answer (score 2):

It's quite confusing, because, as you deduced, there's a  hidden implicit interpolation of attribute values from Face-Corner to Point, when you plug the maths straight into *Set Position*.

In order to sidestep that, you can explicitly execute the comparison in the Face Corner domain:

[image]

Which makes this difference:

[image]